# Replacing specific strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     Basic Stats    Min       Max      Mean     Stdev    Num  Eigenvalue
0      Band 1    0.428944  0.843916  0.689923  0.052534   1    0.229509
1      Band 10  -0.000000  0.689320  0.513170  0.048885   2    0.119217
```

And I want to replace `Band 1` with `LG68` and `Band 10` with `LG69`

I have tried:

```
df=df.replace({'Band 1': 'LG68', 'Band 10': 'LG69'}, regex=True)
```

but this returns:

```
     Basic Stats    Min       Max      Mean     Stdev  Num  Eigenvalue
0      LG68     0.428944  0.843916  0.689923  0.052534  1    0.229509
1      LG680   -0.000000  0.689320  0.513170  0.048885  2    0.119217
```

because Band 10 also contains Band 1 within it.

I have also tried:

```
df=df.T
df=df.rename(columns={'Band 1':'LG68', 'Band10': 'LG69'})
```

but this fails silently (no names change at all), possibly because I don't have Band 1 and Band 10 as column names but are instead actual rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the regex by adding a `$` to the end of `Band 1`, making the statement look like

```
df=df.replace({'Band 1$': 'LG68', 'Band 10': 'LG69'}, regex=True)
```

The `$` matches the end of the line, so that `Band 1$` will only match when `Band 1` is followed by the end of the string or a newline character.  You could also use `\Z`, which only matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using `map` function with a `dict` to describe the mapping relation.

```
df['Basic Stats'] = df['Basic Stats'].map({'Band 1': 'LG68', 'Band 10': 'LG69'})
df

  Basic Stats     Min     Max    Mean   Stdev  Num  Eigenvalue
0        LG68  0.4289  0.8439  0.6899  0.0525    1      0.2295
1        LG69 -0.0000  0.6893  0.5132  0.0489    2      0.1192
```

Comment: That returns all values within `Basic Stats` as `NaN`.

Comment: @StefanoPotter Can you show the result of `df['Basic Stats'].values[:5]` in your original dataframe? The resulting `NaN` is typically a consequence of mismatch between the keys in `dict` and the values in that `Basic Stats` column.

Comment: `['     Band 1' '     Band 2' '     Band 3' '     Band 4' '     Band 5']
['     Band 1' '     Band 2' '     Band 3' '     Band 4' '     Band 5']`  I simplified original post, there are rally 80 bands numbered 1-80 I am doing this for

Comment: @StefanoPotter So there is a whitespace ahead of each band. Try `.map({' Band 1': 'LG68', ' Band 10': 'LG69'})`. Alternatively, try removing the leading or trailing whitespace before mapping.

Comment: There actually shouldn't be whitespace...but even with added space it returns NaN still

Comment: @StefanoPotter Can you upload your sample datafile via dropbox sharelink or google driver? Does `df['Basic Stats'].str.strip().map({'Band 1': 'LG68', 'Band 10': 'LG69'})` work?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting regex to true, so you should be able to just use a regex.   Add $ to match the end of the string.

```
df=df.replace({'Band 1$': 'LG68', 'Band 10$': 'LG69'}, regex=True)
```